# Update a URL Query string in IIS URL Rewrite in IIS

Tags: regex, iis, iis-express, url-rewrite-module

I want to rewrite my URL Querystring in IIS i.e to update my ip=0

so I tried to regex like this

Actual URL

`http://test.com/track/?ip=1&_=12345`

Expected result

`http://api.com/track/?ip=0&_=12345`

MY Regex

`http://test.com/([_0-9a-z-]+)/([?_0-9a-z]+)=([0-9]+)(.*)`

`http://api.com/{R:1}/{R:2}=0{R:4}`

Can you please help me?

Comment: Learn how to format your question body, and then how to troubleshoot rewrite rules, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the different web site, Redirect is a preferable way to Url Rewrite. Otherwise, Rewrite is applicable to the same web site.
https://blogs.iis.net/owscott/url-rewrite-vs-redirect-what-s-the-difference
We need to match the query string, and then we can assign the fragment of the query string to the new action.

```
ip=([0-9]+)&_=([0-9]+)
```

Please refer to the below screenshot.
[image]
WebConfig.

```
<rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="MyRule" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="ip=([0-9]+)&amp;_=([0-9]+)" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://localhost/track?ip=0&amp;_={C:2}" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Here is a related discussion.
[https://forums.iis.net/t/1238891.aspx?Url+Rewrite+with+multiple+querystring+](https://forums.iis.net/t/1238891.aspx?Url%20Rewrite%20with%20multiple%20querystring%20)